# Como obtener datos de la nube o localhost en Android

Tags: android, json

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación Android, para la cual debo manipular un Vector. La inserción de objetos a este Vector la hago de forma manual, cada vez que se ejecuta la aplicación y mantengo los datos en el estado de memoria interna.

Lo que quisiera hacer es poder obtener los datos que uso para instanciar los objetos del Vector, de la nube o utilizar mi propia PC como localhost.

Como si fuera un WebService, quisiera recibir un JSON y poder procesarlo en mi aplicación

¿Podrían orientarme sobre qué herramientas tengo que usar o qué puedo aplicar para esto?

Comment: No me queda claro si la pregunta es cómo obtener un JSON en tu aplicación en Android o cómo generar una aplicación web que almacene los valores nuevos en la base de datos y los devuelva cómo JSON. Además, ¿en qué lenguaje estás trabajando?

Comment: ¿de donde sacarás esa informacion? ¿de una base de datos? ¿con qué lenguaje trabajarias del lado del servidor? Considera detallar más tu pregunta. Es muy amplia

Comment: Segun tus comentarios veo que sabes PHP, del lado del servidor podrías impementar un servicio rest, con laravel eso es muy sencillo, del lado del cliente podrías usar volley o retrofit

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es obtener datos remotos. Necesitaras una fuente de datos, permisos de acceso a la conexión, etc. Dependiendo de los datos que requieres será una u otra. 
Como origen de datos remoto, existen apis públicas, cada una tiene su forma de trabajar y maneja datos concretos, los datos suelen recuperarse mediante peticiones GET como las que hace habitualmente un navegador web al escribir una dirección web o pulsar un enlace (para enviarlos, cambiarlos, etc, deberías estudiar al menos como funcionan las peticiones GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). Como supongo que necesitas datos concretos, requieres un servicio remoto propio, que te sirva los JSON con los datos que quieres. Tendrás que comprarlo o montártelo (si sabes de programación de servidor, es básicamente un sitio web, pero no se crean vistas, lo que generas son JSON, que podrás ver también si accedes con un navegador web, si no puedes programarte un servidor hay servicios de pago como Firebase (pruebas gratis), que te ahorra la programación del lado servidor).

Saludos.

Comment: Quisiera montar mi propio servidor, pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Yo este verano hice uno sencillo con PHP, también se puede montar con node.js si controlas javascript, o con cualquier lenguaje de servidor, manuales hay en la red, pero tienes que controlar alguno de estos lenguajes. Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo de servicio API Rest: http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/crear-api-rest-json-server.html

Comment: Conozco PHP, he hecho algunas cosas pequeñas. Mi duda es, como quedaría mi URL en para que mi aplicación Android pueda servirse del WebService, acaso será http://"mi direccion ip"/"carpeta del proyecto php"?

Comment: La URL es como cualquiera, es el verbo de la petición HTTP el que le tiene que decir al api segun su diseño como interpretarla. Pongamos por ejemplo que quieres ver un usuario, una url puede ser: http://tudominio.com/user/3. Suelen usarse URLs tipo http://api.tudominio.com/user/3 por conveniencia. Esta URL con un api rest, te serviría además para borrar el usuario o editarlo (verbos DEL y PUT). Si tienes una web funcionando puedes añadir respuestas a URL específicas como JSON. Es el servidor el que devuelve HTML o JSON según quieras.